# HP Pavilion g7 -2275dx - Windows 8.1

Tags: drivers

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.03 onto my HP laptop along side Windows ( Dual Boot )
Under the "God Mode" for Windows 8, I have a partition utility - 500GB Free on the system drive, what is recommended for Ubuntu?

Also, driver compatibility - AMD A8 - APU 1.9Ghz quad core, Radeon 7640G Video, 
AMD High Def Audio, with IDT High Def Codec.
Qualcomm Atheros WiFi
Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller

Are there any know issues with any drivers or dual OS with Win 8.1?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I just tried Ubuntu for the first time on the system from DVD, no issues. All drivers with the exception of the AMD Graphics loaded fine. AMD's website has an updated ( 12/19/13 ) driver release for Linux for All AMD APU's

Answer (score 0):

Dual-head g7 is certified for 12.04: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201209-11634/ - although there are many g7 versions, yours may be slightly different.

Disable SecureBoot, there are known issues with it.

You will likely (but not necessarily) need to install AMD proprietary drivers after installing Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```